# React native expo: gyroscope subscription problems with headless JS

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, gyroscope

I am encountering a problem in my react native project. I am using a Gyroscope, implemented according to the official documentation expo:

```js
  const _subscribe = () => {
    setSubscription(
      Gyroscope.addListener((gyroscopeData) => {
        //handle data
      }),
    );
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(1000);
  };

  const _unsubscribe = () => {
    subscription && subscription.remove();
    setSubscription(null);
    Gyroscope.removeAllListeners();
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      _subscribe();
      return () => _unsubscribe();
    }, []),
  );
```

The gyroscope itself does work.

**The first problem** I'm emcountering is I was unable to unsubscribe from the Gyroscope listener, so the solution was to call Gyroscope.removeAllListeners(). This is not according to the official documentation, but subscription is never set to EventSubscription so I was unable to call .remove() on it.

**The second and biggest problem** I'm having has to do with a headless JS function I'm running. When I close the app, I unsubscribe successfully from the Gyroscope by calling Gyroscope.removeAllListeners(), and when I open again I subscribe successfully, but I now receive the following error, and the Gyroscope listener does nothing:

```
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method startObserving on module ExponentGyroscope: Subscription has been released, cannot call methods on a released subscription.
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method setUpdateInterval on module ExponentGyroscope: Subscription has been released, cannot call methods on a released subscription.
```

I am new to react native and expo so am not able to wrap my head around the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards